# How to attach S3 file to email in Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to attach a media file saved in an S3 bucket to an email, which I'm doing with this line of code:

```
email.attach_file(standard.download.url)
```

The model is defined as follows:

```
class Standard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 51)
    download = models.FileField(upload_to="standard_downloads/", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Within `settings.py` I have defined my media files as follows:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'sme.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

When trying to run the code I'm getting

> No such file or directory:
>   'https:/bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/media/standard_downloads/filename.ext

Please note it is showing as `https:/` (a single /).  How do I correct this?

Comment: is this happening on your localhost or some server like nginx or apache etc ?

Comment: I'm running it on an EC2 instance via ElasticBeanStalk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the source code of `attach_file` from Django. It clearly says - to attach file from the **filesystem**. It does not work with remote urls. And when you give it a url it thinks you are referring to local file, so it escapes all double slashes to single slashes.

```
def attach_file(self, path, mimetype=None):
    """
    Attach a file from the filesystem.

    Set the mimetype to DEFAULT_ATTACHMENT_MIME_TYPE if it isn't specified
    and cannot be guessed.

    For a text/* mimetype (guessed or specified), decode the file's content
    as UTF-8. If that fails, set the mimetype to
    DEFAULT_ATTACHMENT_MIME_TYPE and don't decode the content.
    """
    path = Path(path)
    with path.open('rb') as file:
        content = file.read()
        self.attach(path.name, content, mimetype)
```

Django does not provide anything built-in for that. You will have to write something custom on the lines of above code also using libraries like `request` or `boto`. Basically the idea is to fetch from remote url save as temp and then use `attach` on that.

Here's one example on how you could get the file on the fly:

```
from django.core.mail.message import attach
import requests
response = requests.get("http://yoururl/somefile.pdf")
email.attach('My file',response.read(),mimetype="application/pdf")
```

Comment: So if I'm using S3 bucket, how do I attach a file?

Comment: I don't know the mimetype of the file so I did `response = requests.get(standard.download.url)
            email.attach(standard.download.name, response.read())` but now get the error `'Response' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: changed `response.read()` to `response.content` and it works.  Thank you

Comment: or `email.attach(os.path.basename(standard.download.file.name), standard.download.file.read(), "application/pdf")` will automatically retrieve the file for you

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to leverage `default_storage` which will work whether you are using local file storage, S3 or any other storage backend.

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

msg = EmailMessage(
    subject="Your subject",
    body="Your Message",
    from_email="email@yourdomain.com",
    to=["email@anotherdomain.com"],
)
    
filename = "standard_downloads/filename.ext"
with default_storage.open(filename, "r") as fh:
    msg.attach(filename, fh.read())

msg.send()
```